# How to cancel stripe payments after x months?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, subscription

I am developing a wordpress site for my client.
He wants 3 types of payments

1. Individual course - one simple payment
2. Subscription each year
3. 2 payments of x euros on first month and then on second month

How can I cancel/stop after 2 months the third subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to use [SubscriptionSchedules](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules). They allow control of multiple "phases" on a subscription such as the number of iterations (in your case 2), or what to do at the end of a phase (such as switching to a new Price).

You would create a SubscriptionSchedule via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/create) where you have one phase on Price `price_123` and you would set the `iterations` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-phases-iterations) to 2 so that it renew for a second month. You would also set the `end_behavior` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-end_behavior) to `cancel` to indicate that the underlying Subscription should be canceled at the end of the second month automatically.

An alternative would be to simply create a Subscription to Price `price_123` and listen to the `invoice.created` event. On the second month when the new Invoice is created you can use the Update Subscription [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) and set the `cancel_at_period_end` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at_period_end) to `true` to indicate you want the Subscription to stop at the end of that second month.

Comment: Got it, but I need a customer_id and I don't have it, I need to create a checkout page first to take the customer id? I implemented on the way you explained, but where can I pay because it doesn't redirect me to checkout page and I don't have a customer_id...

Comment: If you use Checkout then this option mostly can't work. You can start a Subscription from Checkout and then modify it but it's going to confuse your customers so really you need to build this yourself and collect payment details on your own page via Elements.

Comment: I decided to use checkout and then update Subscription 1.The customer pays for the subscription via Checkout
2. Create a Subscription Schedule for the existing (and already paid for) subscription : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription

Comment: Ah nice, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Spent quite some time trying to figure this out for my similar case. Sharing my code here in case it works for anyone else.

I was trying to update a recurring subscription to bill only three times (for a three-month bootcamp). Doing this through Zapier.

```
import requests

# Input data from subscription event in Zapier
subscription_id = input_data['subscription_id']
price_id = input_data['price_id']
customer_id = input_data['customer_id']

api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"  # Replace with your actual Stripe API key

def update_subscription_schedule(subscription_id, price_id, customer_id):
    """
    Updates the subscription schedule for a given subscription.

    Args:
        subscription_id (str): The ID of the subscription to update.
        price_id (str): The ID of the price. Needed for the update for some reason
        customer_id (str): The ID of the customer 
    Returns:
        dict: A dictionary containing the status code, a message, and other details about the update operation.
    """
    url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_schedules"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }
    payload = {
        "from_subscription": subscription_id,
    }

    try:
        # Create a new subscription schedule from the existing subscription
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        response.raise_for_status()

        subscription_schedule = response.json()
        subscription_schedule_id = subscription_schedule["id"]
        current_phase_start_date = subscription_schedule["current_phase"]["start_date"]
        subscription_coupon = subscription_schedule["phases"][0].get("coupon", None)

        # Update the newly created subscription schedule
        update_url = f"https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_schedules/{subscription_schedule_id}"
        update_payload = {
            "end_behavior": "cancel",
            "phases[0][items][0][price]": price_id,
            "phases[0][items][0][quantity]": 1,
            "phases[0][coupon]": subscription_coupon,
            "phases[0][iterations]": 3,  # Subscription will be billed 3 times (2 more after the initial billing)
            "phases[0][start_date]": current_phase_start_date,
        }

        update_response = requests.post(update_url, headers=headers, data=update_payload)
        update_response.raise_for_status()

        output = {
            "status_code": update_response.status_code,
            "message": "Subscription Schedule updated successfully.",
            "subscription_schedule_id": subscription_schedule_id,
            "current_phase_start_date": current_phase_start_date,
            "subscription_coupon": subscription_coupon,
        }
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        output = {"status_code": e.response.status_code, "message": f"Error: {str(e)}"}

    return output


# Output for Zapier
output = update_subscription_schedule(subscription_id, price_id, customer_id)
```