# Stripe subscription auto cancellation after X months - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, webhooks

I saw [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73093513/how-to-cancel-stripe-payments-after-x-months) and i would like to know if theres any way to cancel subscriptions of certain products at a set amount of months without using Zapier or similar. I had lot issues with Zaps not executing or giving errors and i need a 99% reliable way of managing subscriptions.

I have several products that has a monthly price, how can i set somewhere that whenever somone buys (subscribes) to that product it gets cancelled after 3/6/12 months for example?

Products are created in Stripe, site is in Wordpress, whenever someone clicks the BUY button get redirected to Stripe to finish the order and pay directly there.
Is it also possible to have it all integrated in my wordpress site so the user doesnt leaves the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the customer not to leave your domain or have the Subscription end after X cycles, then you would need both server and client implementation, which I don't know if possible with WordPress.

Custom workflow

- Save the Customer's payment method with a Setup intent (intent is created on the server and confirmed on the client)
  https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements
- Create a Subscription with a finite number of cycles with a Subscription Schedule (serverside exclusively)
  https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#installment-plans

Intermediate workflow

It sounds like what you're using are Payment Links or Stripe Checkout. It's worth mentioning there is a way to embed Checkout session on your domain now - which while not really helpful in the 'ending the subscription after X cycles' does qualify as hosting the payment form on your site instead of Stripe's.

= With this in mind, you could create the Subscription with embedded Checkout:
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?platform=web&ui=embedded-form
-Create a Schedule for your Subscription:
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription
-Add a limited number of cycles for your Schedule:
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#installment-plans